# Как сохранить в свойство базового класса результат действий в производном

Tags: c#, наследование, свойства

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения метода AddIngredient в свойство базового класса возвращалось значение для дальнейшего манипулирования с ним уже в базовом классе?

Есть базовый класс CoffeeMachine в котором находится свойство CoffeeBean

```
internal class CoffeeMachine
{
    public int CoffeeBean { get; set; }
}
```

Так же есть производный класс Ingredients c методом AddIngredient

```
internal class Ingredients : CoffeeMachine
{
    public void AddIngredient()
    {
      CoffeeBean += 900;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит `в свойство базового класса возвращалось значение`? Покажите пример того, что должно получаться.

Comment: Странная логика у вас в коде получается. У вас "Ингредиенты" вдруг являются "Кофемашиной". Вот у вас на столе стоит саха, задайте себе вопрос - он является "Кофемашиной"? Скорей всего вы скажете "Нет". Так почему в коде у вас он этим является? Да и если дальше размышлять, то "Ингредиент для кофемашины", звучит как-то странно. Вот "Ингредиент для кофе" - да, ок (и то это не производное кофе, ибо "Сахар не является кофе). Ну а сам кофе это "Напиток", который имеет "ингредиенты" и который уже "Кофемашина" должна принимать и готовить.

Comment: @eccs0103 Например, через переопределение виртуального метода в производном классе. Переопределённый метод вернёт "значение" в базовый класс.

Comment: Показанный код будет работать нормально, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно более детально изучить наследование в C#. Наследование ещё называют "расширением базового класса". Что это значит? Это значит, что наследуемый/расширяемый класс будет иметь тот же функционал, что в базового, только до этого ещё добавится функционал текущего класса.

Как это всё на практики? Допустим вам нужно что-то сохранить или передать в базовый класс. У нас есть базовый класс:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

И наследуемый:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public void InvokeThisMethod(string toBase)
    {
        Property = toBase; // Here
    }
}
```

Теперь разберём варианты, как это можно сделать другими способами, и что мы получаем из этого.

В дочернем классе мы можем использовать ключевое слово `base`, которое напрямую указывает на родительский элемент. Тогда вызова `Property` выглядел бы вот так:

```
base.Property = toBase;
```

Если вы хотите, что бы `Property` был доступен только для дочерних классов, вы можете использовать к нему модификатор доступа `protected`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда попытка вызова `Property` извне вызовет ошибку:

```
BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.Property = "Something"; // <-- Syntax error
```

Но синтаксис внутри `ChildClass` не потребует изменений и будет работать так само как и до этого

Answer (score -2):

Общие соображения. А они похоже автору как раз таки и нужны. Потому что конкретное "решение" на кофе-машине и кофе-бобах тут вряд ли поможет. Ну потому что судя по тому как автор наследует "землекопа" от "кирпича" - тут всё гораздо глубже, и значит "смотреть" тут нужно гораздо глубже, чем это представляется автору.

То что хочет сделать автор - это переопределить метод базового класса. Простейший способ - это виртуализация метода базового класса.

Объявите метод базового класса - виртуальным. А затем переопределите этот метод в производном классе. И базовый класс будет "дёргать" как раз таки переопределённый метод в производном классе.

Как это работает на примере? Понятное дело что "трогать" кофе-машину и бобы - не стоит, там всё запущено. А вот например "потрогать" простейшие реализации виртуальных ToString(), GetHashCode(), Equals() - пожалуй можно. Это хорошие, годные примеры. И разобравшись в этом - автор разберётся и со своим "кофе".

Пример: Есть класс System.Object и у этого класса есть виртуальные методы. Это то, что нужно автору. Это например ToString(). Как это работает? ToString() в базовом классе System.Object - виртуальный. И может быть переопределён в производном классе. И этот метод возвращает строку. В базовый класс. Т.е. в производном классе можно переопределить ToString(). А базовый класс будет дёргать это переопределение метода, и базовый класс получит строку из производного класса.

```
public class Object
{
    // Этот метод вызывается, когда нужно "строковое" представление объекта
    // Этот метод может быть переопределён в производном классе
    // Переопределённый метод (если он есть) будет вызываться, а не этот
    // Вызов этого метода из базового класса будет дёргать переопределённый
    // метод из производного класса, т.е. на самом деле выдернется
    // строка из производного класса, а не строка "System.Object"
    public virtual string ToString()
    {
        return "System.Object";
    }
}
```

Производный класс от Object, с переопределённым ToString():

```
public class Derived : Object
{
    // Переопределение метода, теперь ToString() другой
    // Базовый Object будет пользовать именно этот переопределённый метод
    // И получит переопределённую строку
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Переопределение строки, возвращает строку в базовый класс
        return "Переопределение метода, возвращает переопределённую строку";
    }
}
```

Метод для переопределения в базовом классе помечается как **virtual**. А переопределяемый метод в производном классе помечается как **override**. Обратите внимание.

А теперь всё то же самое можно сделать на кофе-машине и на кофе-бобах. Но это предлагается сделать автору самостоятельно. Автору нужно создать корректный родительский класс, там определить **собственный** виртуальный метод по бобам, затем создать производный класс и переопределить этот метод в производном классе. И получить значение этого метода (результат этого метода) в базовом классе.

П.С.: Наследовать ингредиенты от кофе-машины не следует. Ингредиенты и кофе-машина не являются прямыми наследниками/родителями друг относительно друга.
П.П.С.: Объяснение на уровне "языка", но на самом деле на уровне "рантайма" - объяснение на уровне "языка" не годится. На уровне рантайма объяснение совершенно другое. Но оно здесь не нужно.